# How to filter by a property value of the entity class rather than the id in javers?

Tags: javers

Javers Query Language can filter by ByClass, ByInstanceId where id is the field marked with @Id. But my requirement is that it should filter by any other field in my class.

Tried various JQL API and read through the documentation to understand that this feature is not supported.

```
@Entity
class Person{

  @javax.persistence.Id
  private String id;

  @org.javers.core.metamodel.annotation.Id
  private String personName;

..Getters/Setters

}
```

I would like to write JQL based on person name instead of id. May be by adding a Javers @id annotation over there. Since person is also unique for me it will help in filtering on that since the end user understands personName instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `withCommitProperty` for example:

```
QueryBuilder jqlQuery = QueryBuilder.byClass(Person.class).withCommitProperty("personName","john");
List<CdoSnapshot> snapshots = javers.findSnapshots(jqlQuery.build());
```

Comment: I think commit properties are different. They are associated with every commit id and have nothing to do with state of the object being committed.